# Getting "Unable to autoload constant" .. '"expected app/lib/subfolder/module.rb to define it"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, module

I'm trying to load the module:

```
 #MainApp/app/lib/game/pieces.rb
  module Pieces
    class Pawn
        def initialize
           puts "I'm a piece!"
        end
     end
  end
```

In the model:

```
 # MainApp/app/models/boardgame.rb
 class Boardgame < ApplicationRecord
   include Game::Pieces
 end
```

But i get "Unable to autoload constant Game::Pieces, expected /home/..MainApp/app/lib/game/pieces.rb to define it (LoadError)"

I tried to set the folder in the autoload_paths and eager_load_paths:

```
 # config/application.rb
 module MainApp
   class Application < Rails::Application
      config.load_defaults 5.2
      config.autoload_paths << Rails.root.join('app/lib/game')
      config.eager_load_paths << Rails.root.join('app/lib/game')
   end
 end
```

but it still doesn't work, if i put the module in app/lib it loads it perfectly, the problem occurs only in a subfolder.

Comment: You define `Pieces::Piece` in `MainApp/app/lib/game/pieces.rb` but are trying to include `Game::Piece`. That doesn't make sense, yes?

Comment: You are missing naming convention...

Comment: I realize that, now :/ thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you include `Game::Pieces` your module should look like that:

```
module Game
  module Pieces
    # some code here
  end
end
```

In addition to that, the preferred way of structuring in Ruby and Rails is to name your directory according to your module name, so your module path would rather be `lib/game/pieces.rb`.
And please consider including a module, not a class

Answer (score 1):

You have defined a class `Piece` in a module `Pieces`, but you expect a class `Piece` in a module game. You need to change the code in `MainApp/app/lib/game/pieces.rb` to

```
  module Game
    class Piece
        def initialize
           puts "I'm a piece!"
        end
     end
  end
```